# What is special about simplices, circles, paths and cubes?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, category-theory

There are some ubiquitous families of graphs — the complete graphs (or simplices) $K_n$, the circle graphs $C_n$, the path graphs $P_n$, and the hypercube graphs $Q_n$ — that intuitively seem to play a special role, not only in graph theory.

Can this intuition be made rigorous somehow, maybe by categorical means?

Observations making them "special" (but not unique):

- They are examples of "categorical" graph properties: there is exactly *one* graph for every $n$. (Of course there are many, many other such families - e.g. wheels or stars -, but *these* are the most common ones, I guess.)
- $K_1 = C_1 = P_1 = Q_1$
  $K_2 = C_2 = P_2 \neq Q_2$
  $K_3 = C_3 \neq P_3 \neq Q_3$
  $K_n \neq C_n \neq P_n \neq Q_n$ for $n>3$
- They have to do with fundamental classes of topological structures: balls, tori, and euclidean spaces.
- *ADDED*: They are - except for the path graphs - regular and vertex-transitive. The path graphs are at least "almost" regular (and the double-infinite path graph $\mathbb{Z}$ *is* even vertex-transitive).

What I am looking for is something like a categorical characterization, e.g. "being universal (= initial or terminal) objects" in some (not too) specialized graph categories.

And I'd like to learn whether there are other families of graphs of this kind (whatever "this kind" may be).

Comment: I think vertex transitivity is by far the most significant here. A direct product of the infinite binary tree and a cycle makes for the space of … :) Yeah, maybe it can be made into a continuous space as the integers are to the reals. Or even such a product of 2 infinite binary trees. I think in general there all reasonably described as grids, even complete graphs.